# Smart indenting in vim (normally great) is a disaster when pasting in a chunk of code

Tags: vim, terminal, text-editor, copy-paste

I guess other editors are smart enough to turn that stuff off for pasting but when using vim in a terminal it can't distinguish between pasting and actual typing.

What kinds of solutions or workarounds do you have for this?

Added: there's also a setting that makes comments automatically continue on the next line.  The indenting at least doesn't change the semantics of the code but the auto comment continuation really screws things up.  Come to think of it, I should just turn that off altogether -- anyone know what that option is called?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

:set paste is the way to go, but if you forget, as I often do, then if you are using a language with {} as the open/close of blocks, then doing a =% on the first { or last } will reapply the indenting.

Comment: This actually works with any language plugin that correctly defines blocks -- ruby, for example, can do this from the `end`.

Answer (score 15):

:set paste

Comment: :set nopaste - to turn indenting back on

Comment: oh ho, thanks.  so you have to remember to set it and unset it before and after pasting?  I guess nothing more automatic is possible without a programmatic way to distinguish pasting and typing.

Comment: You could use Key Mapping to bind it to a set of keys. But I have never tried this. http://www.shlomifish.org/lecture/Vim/beginners/slides/slide30.html

Comment: Cool, want to incorporate that into your answer?  And maybe add something about the feature that automatically continues commenting, if you know what I'm talking about there.

Comment: @dreeves: automatically continued commenting is also disabled by :set paste

Comment: Good point, although in that case there isn't a simple ex-post fix like there is with indenting so I think I'd rather just turn that feature off.

Comment: @dreeves: :set fo-=r

:he fo-table for more info on all the stuff you can set

Comment: (doh, forgot no linebreaks in comments -- :he is a separate command obviously... and now I will stop derailing this comment thread)

Comment: This is also helpful: `au InsertLeave * set nopaste` -- no one wants that left on!

Answer (score 7):

add this to your .vimrc and use it with the F2 key to toggle paste status before and after you add in chunks of code:

```
set pastetoggle=<F2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this, assuming you have your system clipboard set up properly is to do

```
"*p
```

This will paste from the system clipboard.

Check your `vim --version`. On OS X you'll need `+clipboard` and on Linux `+xterm_clipboard`, I believe.

If you're on OS X, you can always `brew install macvim` and use `mvim -v` instead of the bundled Vim (it was not compiled with `+clipboard`).

Comment: check your vim --version. look for +xterm_clipboard or +clipboard. I use mvim -v. I have -xterm_clipboard but +clipboard and it works fine.